# Do you get an error when right clicking read only text on a completed activity in dynamic crm 2011?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

Right Click -> Copy on a read only field on a completed activity in dynamics 2011 always causes an error. Not a show stopper perhaps (CTRL+C works) but a pain.

Following is the Error message.
**'srcElement.tagName' is null or not an object**

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't, works fine for me. I have to highlight the text first though.

What rollup are you on? Also which version of IE are you using?

Comment: iam using IE 8 and Rollup 5, copy the field and try to close the window,getting microsoft error.

Comment: Arr, well im on IE 9 and Rollup 8, try installing the latest rollup.